# How to get a legend for a WMS layer and search in it?

Tags: qgis, wms

How to bring legend and search for WMS layer in QGis? I can see the WMS layer in Qgis but can't make any legend for identifying feature types and searching in WMS layer?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search in a WMS layer because a WMS doesn't have an attribute table. It's just an image.

The missing legend is still a missing feature. I don't know if a feature request has been filed for that. I'd imagine the author of WMS code is aware of it.

Comment: Is it possible to get feature info like we do in web?

Comment: Yes. As with all other layers, the "Identify" tool works with WMS too.